# Cosmos DB Change Feeds in a Kubernetes Cluster with arbitrary number of pods

Tags: kubernetes, azure-cosmosdb, azure-aks, azure-cosmosdb-changefeed

I have a collection in my Cosmos database that I would like to observe for changes. I have many documents (official and unofficial) explaining how to do this. There is one thing though that I cannot get to work in a reliable way: how do I receive the same changes to multiple instances when I don't have any common reference for instance names?

What do I mean by this? Well, I'm running my work loads in a Kubernetes cluster (AKS). I have a variable number of instances within the cluster that should observe my collection. In order for change feeds to work properly, I have to have a unique instance name for each instance. The only candidate I have is the pod name. It's usually on the form of `<deployment-name>-<random string>`. E.g. `pod-5f597c9c56-lxw5b`.

If I use the pod name as instance name, all instances do not receive the same changes (which is my requirement), only one instance will receive the change (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor#dynamic-scaling). What I can do is to use the pod name as feed name instead, then all instances get the same changes. This is what I fear will bite me in the butt at some point; when peek into the lease container, I can see a set of documents per feed name. As pod names come and go (the random string part of the name), I fear the container will grow over time, generating a heap of garbage. I know Cosmos can handle huge work loads, but you know, I like to keep things tidy.

How can I keep this thing clean and tidy? I really don't want to invent (or reuse for that matter!) some protocol between my instances to vote for which instance gets which name out of a finite set of names.

One "simple" solution would be to build my own instance names, if AKS or Kubernetes held some "index" of some sort for my pods. I know stateful sets give me that, but I don't want to use stateful sets, as the pods themselves aren't really stateful (except for this particular aspect!).

Comment: I think I might have found a workaround. The question revolves around the change feed processor in the Cosmos SDK. I have found the feed iterators now, and I think I could pull this one off with my own custom solution.

Answer (score 1):

There is a new [Change Feed pull model](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-pull-model) (which is in preview at this time).

The differences are:

[image: change feed push model versus change feed processor]

In your case, it looks like you don't need parallelization (you want all instances to receive everything). The important part would be to design a state storing model that can maintain the continuation tokens (or not, maybe you don't care to continue if a pod goes down and then restarts).

Comment: Yeah, I found the iterator/pull model, but unfortunately it's in preview. I am a bit wary of using preview dependencies in a high volume production environment. I have (for now) solved it by using multiple feeds, and on shutdown I delete `<feedname>*` in the lease container. As soon as the pull model comes out of preview, I will use that.

Comment: I see you're on the Cosmos development team (or at least you've contributed judging by PR discussions). Do you have any details to share as to when the feature comes out of preview?

Comment: We don't have any official GA date yet as we are still gathering feedback to define which is the final API. The functionality should not change, but the API surface (method parameters or names) might (or not, depending on feedback) slightly change.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you proceed to use the pod name as unique ID. If you are concerned about sprawl of the data, you could monitor the container and devise a clean-up mechanism for the metadata.

In order to have at-least-once delivery, there is going to need to be metadata persisted somewhere to track items ACK-ed / position in a partition, etc. I suspect there could be a bit of work to get change feed processor to give you at-least-once delivery once you consider pod interruption/re-scheduling during data flow.

As another option Azure offers an implementation of checkpoint based [message sharing from partitioned event hubs via EventProcessorClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-processor-balance-partition-load). In EventProcessorClient, there is also a bit of metadata added to a storage account.